# How do I manage proxies with QT QWebView

Tags: qt, qt4, proxy, qwebview, qnetworkaccessmanager

This is how I change proxy:

```
QNetworkProxy proxy;
proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy);
proxy.setHostName("ip");
proxy.setPort(8008);

QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);
```

It works properly if I do it before I create WebView. But if I change proxies during life time of QWebView, it simply wont load any site. What's the proper way of changing proxy on fly in QT?

Thanks.

Comment: A note in the doc for QNetworkProxy says " Note: Changes made to currently connected sockets do not take effect. If you need to change a connected socket, you should reconnect it." . Also have you tried webview->page()->networkAccessManager()->setProxy(proxy);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[QWebPage::setNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebpage.html#networkAccessManager) method documents says that

*Note: It is currently not supported to change the network access manager after the QWebPage has used it. The results of doing this are undefined.*

So my guess is that once you setup an application wide proxy and once QWebPage is constructed it gets a QNetworkAccessManager and you can not change its proxy settings.

As an alternative to using an application wide proxy, you probably can create a new QNetworkAccessManager and use its QNetworkAccessManager::setProxy() method to to setup a proxy. Then pass this QNetworkAccessManager  instance to your web page.

Anyway you need to play with it. I hope this helps.